# Why some files does not come with content_type when uploaded [.log, .srt, etc]?

Tags: file-upload, mime-types

My database table for `Attachments` have a column for content_type (MIME types) to store "image/jpg, "application/pdf".

But some misc files, such as ".srt, .log", does not come with content_type.

Why they don't have it?

Should I store the extension name instead of the type then?

Thanks!